# Log in to website using Jsoup

Tags: http, jsoup

I'm trying to scrap a webpage for data but came across the problem of needing to log in.

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://www.rapidnyc.net/users/google_login")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();

 Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.rapidnyc.net/users/google_login")
        .data("Email", "testEmail")
        .data("Passwd", "testPass")
        .... //other form data
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .post(); 

This gives me the org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400
```

I used chrome developer tool to look at the Form data being posted but nothing I post works.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Have you submitted **ALL** input fields? Including **HIDDEN** ones.

**2.** I see the website requires "captcha-box" authentication, which is to prevent web crawlers from logging in. I highly doubt you will be able to log in with your program.

I say the 400 status is coming from your program not being able to provide the value for "captcha" authentication.